# Clearing app_webview cache directory in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I wish to clear my `/data/data/com.myapp/app_webview/Cache` folder.

I tried doing it in native by adding this code in `CordovaApp.java` file:

```
WebView obj;
obj.clearCache(true);
```

after this line:

```
loadUrl(launchUrl);
```

It gave an error, so I tried it using `removeRecursively` method. It still didn't work; it gave me an unknown error, i.e none from the ones they've listed here: http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.file

Answer (score 0):

This plugin helped me accomplish the task:

https://github.com/Sharinglabs/cordova-plugin-cache.

It is compatible with Cordova 3.3.1 and above. It works with my Cordova 4.2.0 app.